# GitHub can't publish my website even after running deploy

Tags: reactjs, github

I created a react website and after deploying on GitHub, I added deploy and predepoly and I added the home page to script file, GitHub still didn't publish my website

on index.js

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Browser Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

```
 "homepage": "https://mohamedaly77.github.io/Travelgo/",
  "name": "travelgo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
```

```
"private": false
```

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```